# 22.04-1 and nvidia legacy driver vs nouveau

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, 22.04

im using 22.04 with legacy nvidia driver 340.108 on kernel 5.15.0-60-generic,
proposed want to upgrade kernel to 5.19.0-32 but if i do that i will loose my driver

there is any solution for this case please i do not want to switch again with nouveau wich is really bad with my config ?

i can't believe nobody ask this before that im struggling since weeks with them ( i was with 22.10 and nouveau replace nvidia legacy driver but so poor performance i switched back to 22.04 and kerbelec ppa )

but now im stuck again same kernel will arrive and i will loose my driver

thank you

Comment: There is no official supprt for nvidia-340 with either 5.15 or 5.19 kernels. The last one supported by Ubuntu was kernel 5.8 in 20.04. So, use what works, and do not switch.

Comment: ho that s not what i was expected, to be clear i can not use nouveau except changing my computer, it 's a bit rough.

Comment: Well, why did you think there is no nvidia-340 in 22.04's repositoris, so that you needed to use a questionable ppa? Anyway, the comuter is probably old, and would not benefit from newer kernels.